# Can't get property from object correctly from filter function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
[{foo : 'blar', baz: 'hey'}, {x : 'fum', baz: 'another hey'},{x : 'ack', baz: 'yet another hey'} ]
.map(obj => {
    for (var prop in obj){ 
     if (prop !== 'baz'){ 
        return {prop : obj[prop]};
     }
    }
})
```

I'd like to get an array which contains these objects sans the`baz` property in each.

I am getting this right now....

```
[
 {prop: "blar"},
 {prop: "fum"},
 {prop: "ack"}
]
```

Should be:

```
[
 {foo: "blar"},
 {x: "fum"},
 {x: "ack"}
]
```

Comment: Your `return` inside the `for` loop cancels the loop immediately which is ok for now since your objects only have 2 properties but would exclude others if there were more. I think it should be obvious why your keys are all `prop`

Comment: Why not just delete `baz`? `[{foo : 'blar', baz: 'hey'}, {x : 'fum', baz: 'another hey'},{x : 'ack', baz: 'yet another hey'}].map(item=>(delete item.baz, item));`

Comment: `var a = [{foo : 'blar', baz: 'hey'}, {x : 'fum', baz: 'another hey'},{x : 'ack', baz: 'yet another hey'} ]
.map(obj => {
    for (var prop in obj){ 
     if (prop !== 'baz'){ 
       var ab = {};
        ab[prop] = obj[prop]
        return ab;
     }
    }
});
` You can try this.